# Rails i18n shows translated text surrounded by [" "]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

When trying to use i18n in rails I get the following undesired output.

The translated text is surrounded by `[" "]` so for example:

`hello: "Hello"`

`<%= t(:hello) %>`

is displayed like ["Hello"]

Any idea why that is?

### UPDATE

en.yml

`en:`

`hello: "Hello"`

Usage

`<%= t(:hello) %>`

That it...

Comment: can you display more of the line of code the translation is on?

Comment: `<%= t(:hello).to_a.inspect %>` would display `["hello"]`, for example. Check if there's something similar in your actual code. Show us the actual line from the yml file as well as the `<%= .. %>` code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but could you try using it like :

```
<%= t('hello') %>
```

This is how i use it without any problems :)

Comment: Actually it works, was my setup that messed it all up - Thanks